# CHECKPOINT-FAIL com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: this.waitForCondition is not a function

Tags: exception, selenium

A simple function defined in the user-extensions.js :

```
Selenium.prototype.doGetThis = function(){
    var errors = "";
    if (browserVersion.isChrome) {
        errors = true;
    } else {
        throw new SeleniumError("TODO: Non-FF browser...");
    }
    return errors;
}
```

The Selenium.java file:

```
String getThis() {
    return this.commandProcessor.doCommand("getThis", EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
}
```

Running the test throws a SeleniumException:

```
CHECKPOINT-FAIL com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: this.waitForCondition is not a function
```

Could this exception be avoided?

**Settings:**

- selenium server 2.0a5
- firefox 3.6.11

After I added the ; I still got the same exception.

```
Selenium.prototype.doGetThis = function(){
    var errors = "";
    if (browserVersion.isChrome) {
        errors = true;
    } else {
        throw new SeleniumError("TODO: Non-FF browser...");
    }
    return errors;
};
```

Comment: The problem has been solved by using an accessor instead of an action: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html#accessors-assertions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add a `;` to the end of your `doGetThis` function:

```
Selenium.prototype.doGetThis = function(){
    var errors = "";
    if (browserVersion.isChrome) {
        errors = true;
    } else {
        throw new SeleniumError("TODO: Non-FF browser...");
    }
    return errors;
};
```